# define enum from a json file in typescript / javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to define an `enum` from a **json** file.

I would like to have json files in a ressource folder for all my types.

My code will define enums according to these json files.

something like this:

```
const Metadata = require('./meta.json');

export enum Io // I would like to link Metadata.io to that enum
```

Comment: Maybe `export enum [Metadata.io]`? That may work...

Comment: @JackBashford, doesn't work.